# Pattern matching in gremlin

Tags: java, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a graph with labels users and i want to search the users by name this is the current implementation

```
wg.addV("users").property("p1", "user1").property("p2", "test").next();
```

now i need to search for the users having their property1 or property2 starts with the letters as user type in search.

if user typed "u" i need to get the users whose p1 or p2 starts with "u".
if user typed "use" i need to get the users whose p1 or p2 starts with "use".

and i need to display in relevant order and limit to 10 results.

this is the current implementation.

```
g.V().or(has("users", "p1", between("use", "use" + "z")),
                    has("users", "p2", between("use", "use" + "z")))
            .limit(10))
```

with this approach im able to the users but its not relevant and it is not including the users that match the exact query and order by p1.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the release of TinkerPop 3.4.0, Gremlin also supports simple text predicates

In this case, you should use `startingWith`.

```
g.V().or(
    has('users', 'firstname', startingWith('use')),
    has('users', 'lastname', startingWith('use'))
  ).limit(10)
```

example: https://gremlify.com/sdgnafh8md